# Display an auto bash script run after root logs in

Tags: linux, redhat

Here, I want to display an auto run bash script which I made after the root logs in I tried editing the .bashrc by command `nano ~/.bashrc` And I wrote in it `su root script.sh` but I found that I have to open the terminal manually to run the script so is there a way to display the terminal which runs the script automatically ??

Comment: If you mean 'when root logs in the GUI' Won't that depend on whether you use kde, gnome, or something else like xfce?

Comment: Put your command in ~/.profile file

Comment: @RahulRDhobi you mean to write this command "nano ~/.profile " or this "nano ~/.bash_profile" ??? Sorry for this bad question I am beginner to Linux :)

Comment: @RahulRDhobi the terminal didn't start automatically running the script .. Any help ??

Comment: @user3476633: which OS you are using?

Comment: @RahulRDhobi windows 7 and installed the redhat as VM

Comment: @user3476633:root user is going to logged via ssh/desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your command in startup application please refer http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/RHEL_6_Desktop_-_Starting_Applications_on_Login

you need to add `"gnome-terminal -e /yourpath/script.sh"` in command name in startup applications.

After adding your command please logout and login again

Comment: Is there a way to edit only in bash_profile or bashrc ??

Comment: By the way I don't have thw startup application menu is preferences :'(

Comment: Yes you can add "gnome-terminal -e /yourpath/script.sh &" in ~/.bash_profile :)

Comment: After that logout and login again you can see terminal

Comment: I added it in bash_profile before statement export path and the terminal didn't appear :(

Comment: you need to add it to last line